# How to close a connection created with asyncio.open_connection?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import threading

async def run_local():
    server_address = 'www.facebook.com'
    server_port = 443

    # server_address = 'localhost'
    # server_port = 9012

    for i in range(3):
        protocol = asyncio.Protocol()

        r, w = await asyncio.open_connection(server_address, server_port)

        print('Opened connection')

        await asyncio.sleep(3)

        print('Try to close connection')

        # writer.close()
        # await writer.wait_closed()
        w.close()
        await w.wait_closed()

        print('Close successfully')

    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        for t in threading.enumerate():
            print(t)

asyncio.run(run_local())
```

after the code runs over, there is a MainThread and a ThreadPoolExcutor-0_x always RUNNING, does this behavior right? if not, how to destroy the thread

Comment: ``asyncio`` keeps a background thread executor *which it manages itself*. Why do you want to destroy it if you did not create it?

Comment: in my complete project, I will use `asyncio.open_connection` to create many connections, and after every connection closed, the thread remains, finally there will have too many thread existing, this is why I think this is wrong behavior and why I want to  destroy the thread manually

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] *for the actual problem* then. After calling ``run_local`` 10 times in ``asyncio.run``, ``threading.enumerate()`` shows only a single thread for me. Similarly, calling ``run_local`` 10 times in a separate ``asyncio.run`` each,  ``threading.enumerate()`` also shows only a single thread for me

Comment: I have updated the code of the question, there will always have 3 thread RUNNING until the last loop  running

Comment: This code does not seem to reproduce the problem alluded to in comments. The threads are *not* tied to a specific connection, but reused. Even running this code for a long time will not run more than the 3 threads required to handle the 3 connections at once. What makes you think that "finally there will have too many thread existing"?

Comment: Because the output of the code finally become this:

Comment: <_MainThread(MainThread, started 139847879721344)>
<WriterThread(pydevd.Writer, started daemon 139847848752896)>
<ReaderThread(pydevd.Reader, started daemon 139847840360192)>
<PyDBCommandThread(pydevd.CommandThread, started daemon 139847759034112)>
<CheckAliveThread(pydevd.CheckAliveThread, started 139847750641408)>
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon 139847742248704)>
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon 139847733741312)>
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2, started daemon 139847725348608)>

Comment: ``pydevd`` is a debugger. The code as shown will *not* create any such threads. You are likely looking at threads created by your IDE. Executed with just the regular interpreter, the only threads are ``<_MainThread(MainThread, started ...)>``, ``<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_0, started daemon ...)>``, ``<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_1, started daemon ...)>`` and ``<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-0_2, started daemon ...)>``, which are reused over and over again.

Comment: Yes, `pydevd` is a debugger, the thread with prefix `ThreadPoolExecutor-0` is created when connection made, eg. is tied to a connection

Comment: No, they are not tied to a connection. If you look at the id of the thread, you can see that the same 3 threads get re-used. This code does *not* grow additional threads over time. What you are observing is the usual growth of a [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor) *up to but not beyond* the task size.

Comment: No, if you change to the for loop to run 10 times, eg open 10 connection and close them, the finally thread count will be 10,

Comment: The finally thread count always equal to the open_connection function run times.

Comment: Finally, I find the reason, if you open_connection with a domain name, asyncio will create a thread, if you open_connection with an IP address, it will not create a thread, I think the thread may be tied to a DNS resolve function

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/base_events.py#L856 When open_connection with a domain name, eventloop will try to resolve it, this action will create another thread, see the code above

Comment: https://bugs.python.org/issue41456  This is a feature, not a bug, the loop will create some thread, and then reuse it, I just test with Python 3.7.8, 60 thread has been created, no more thread be created